# Finding bounds for recurrence relation

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Prove that for the recuurence relation $f(n) = 2f(n-1) + f(n-2)$

with the starting values: *f(1) = 1, f(2) = 6*, $\forall n \ge 2$

$$(7/3)^n \le f(n) \le (5/2)^n$$

I tried using the fact that $f(n) \gt 2f(n-1)$

Comment: you can find $f(n)$ explicitly by solving $x^2=2x+1$

Comment: also, a simple induction should work

Comment: @Epiksalad yes it does

Comment: $a_n$ is given by $$a_n=\frac{14 \left(1-\sqrt{2}\right)^n+11 \sqrt{2} \left(1-\sqrt{2}\right)^n+2
   \left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)^n+5 \sqrt{2} \left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)^n}{4
   \left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)}$$

Answer (score 0):

For $n = 1$ you get $7/3 \le 1 \le 5/2$. This is false. So the claim is wrong.

If you want bounds, try looking for an upper bound of the form $f(n) \le a_2 \cdot b^n$, substitute into the recurrence and see what happens:

$\begin{align*}
   f(n)
     &=    2 f(n - 1) + f(n - 2) \\
     &\le  2 a_2 b^{n - 1} + a_2 b^{n - 2} \\
     &=    a_2 b^{n - 2} (2 b + 1)
\end{align*}$

We want $a_2 b^n \le a_2 b^{n - 2} (2 b + 1)$, i.e. $b^2 = 2 b + 1$, positive zero is $1 + \sqrt{2} < 5/2$. Adjust $a_2$ to satisfy the bound for the initial values, i.e. $1 \le a_2 (1 + \sqrt{2})$ and $6 \le a_2 (1 + \sqrt{2})^2 = a_2 (3 + 2 \sqrt{2})$. The first gives $a_2 \ge \sqrt{2} - 1$, the second one $a_2 \ge 18 - 12 \sqrt{2}$. The later is larger, a bit more than 1. Thus we can say $f(n) \le (5/2)^n$

Do the same, but looking for a lower bound. As above, for $f(1) = 1$ you get $a_1 b < 1$, $a_1 < 2/5$, bound $b < 12/5$, giving $2/5 \cdot (12/5)^n < f(n)$; it would be simpler to just say $(2/5)^n \le f(n)$.

The bounds can be checked by induction.